# How Does Line Frequency Affect Coils of a Contactor?

Tags: ac, frequency, coil, line, contactor

I am using a generator as my source voltage, which produces 240VAC @ 240Hz. I was planning to use the following contactor from TE: [CONTACTOR 4PST 40A 240V](https://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=1308242_93-3100-4P&DocType=DS&DocLang=English)

In the datasheet it says this contactor's coil's activating voltage needs to be 50/60Hz. Now what happens if I feed 240VAC @ 240Hz to the activating coil?

I have asked the same question from DigiKey and TE support people, and they just said it won't work; but they did not explain **WHY** it won't work. So, I was hoping if someone could explain it to me why it won't work.

Thanks

Comment: -- Clarification : What generator are you using that is 240 VAC @ 240 Hz?  Normal generator output frequencies are 50/60/400 Hz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An AC coil presents a specific impedance at a specific frequency.

\begin{equation}
X = 2\pi fL
\end{equation}
Where:

L = coil inductance in Henrys

f = frequency

X = impedance

Your contactor's coil is specified at 50-60Hz.  If you instead use 240Hz, then the impedance will be higher, and not enough current will flow through the coil to activate it.

X above can be substituted as R in Ohms law V=IR => V=IX to show how much current will flow.